# How to create a rectangle wave (duty cycle $\ne$ 50 %)?

Tags: functions, periodic-function

I'm trying to use phase-shifted `SquareWave[]` functions to create a rectangle wave:

```
SquareWave[{0, 1}, x/100] * SquareWave[{0, 1}, x/100 - offsetx]
```

Two things:

1. This only allows for duty cycles less than 50 %.
2. While it's handy (it's always the phase shift $0\dots 1$, regardless of horizontal scale), I'm confused that `offsetx` isn't a function of the `x` scaling

Is there a general function to create rectangle waves with duty cycles from 0 % to 100 %?

Comment: (FWIW, I think this is more of a math question than a *Mathematica* question.)

Comment: One elegant solution for duty cycle under 50% would be to multiply two phase-shifted square waves together. I cannot think of an easy analogue for duty cycles in excess of 50%.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

See if this helps

```
squareWave[t_, period_, duty_] := UnitBox[Mod[t/period, 1.]/(2. duty)]

Plot[squareWave[t, 10, 0.8], {t, -2, 21}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: As a tiny note, `Mod[x, 1] == SawtoothWave[x]`. :) That allows us to write `squareWave[t_, period_, duty_] := UnitBox[SawtoothWave[{0, .5}, t/period]/duty]`

Comment: Niiiice :). Put it in yours

Answer (score 6):

What I'd do:

```
With[{d = 1/3}, (* duty cycle *)
 Plot[(1 + (-1)^Floor[x] (-1)^Floor[d - x])/2, {x, -5, 5}, 
  Axes -> {False, True}, Frame -> True, PlotPoints -> 105, 
  PlotRange -> {-5/4, 5/4}]]
```

[image: square wave with duty cycle 1/3]

If you absolutely must use the `SquareWave[]` function, there is the identity

$$\text{SquareWave}[\{a,b\},x]=\frac{a+b}{2}+\frac{b-a}{2}(-1)^{\lfloor 2 x\rfloor}$$

I'll leave the conversion up to you.

Answer (score 2):

You can make any duty cycle you want by combining `TriangleWave` and `Sign`:

```
Sign[TriangleWave[t] - a]
```

As `a` goes from +/-1, you get all possible duty cycles. To see this:

```
Manipulate[Plot[Sign[TriangleWave[t] - a], {t, -3, 3}, 
      Exclusions -> None], {a, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
Plot[SquareWave[{0, 3}, Mod[x, 0.7]], {x, 0, 3}, ExclusionsStyle -> Dotted]
```

Where you can change the 0.7 to your duty cycle.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Mod[x, 0.7] this 0.7 is just a example I used in that code. You can put any value from 0 to 1. But It is already answered by J.M. in the 1st comment to the voted answer

Answer (score 0):

```
Manipulate[duty, EmitSound@AudioGenerator[{"Pulse", 440(*Hz*), 0(*phase*), duty}]], 
          {duty, 0.1, 0.5}]
```

You can see what happened that `duty` do

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following identity:
$$\text{SquareWave}(t;t_{min},t_{max},T)=\left\lfloor\dfrac{t-t_{min}}{T}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor \frac{t-t_{max}}{T}\right\rfloor$$
So you can write this as:

```
SquareWave[tmin_,tmax_,T_,t_] := Floor[(t-tmin)/T] - Floor[(t-tmax)/T];
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Having this in Mathematica code would be preferable.