# How to make a square wave function with controllable period, phase and duty cycle that can work really fast?

Tags: functions, performance-tuning, periodic-function

I actually need two things:

1. A square wave function that allows me to control its duty cycle, period and phase.
2. It must work fast enough to be evaluated at least a million times per second.

For the first problem, I found a number of solutions. Some of them may be found here: [How to create a rectangle wave (duty cycle $\ne$ 50 %)?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7748)

The best one that I tried yet is as follows:

```
squareWave[period_, duty_, phase_,  x_] := Sign[TriangleWave[x/period - phase] - 1 + 2 duty]
```

Unfortunately, on my current machine it takes about 34 seconds to evaluate it 10^6 times. To compare with, `Sin[x]` evaluates 10^6 times in 0.09 seconds.

Is it even possible to achieve my goal? And how?

Comment: Try `squareWave[x_, period_: 1, duty_: (1/2), phase_: 0] := Sign[Mod[x + phase period, period] - (1 - duty) period]`

Comment: The test that gives 34 seconds is actually `AbsoluteTiming[Do[squareWave[1, 0.5, 0, 0.3], 10^6]]` with the definition of `squareWave` provided above. Some insignificant details were omitted to simplify the question. I have a PC that can handle the same task in 7 seconds but it's still too slow. I tried your definition with the test `AbsoluteTiming[Do[squareWave[0.3], 10^6]]` on a good PC and it just took 8 seconds instead of 7.

Comment: Btw, the good PC evaluates `AbsoluteTiming[Do[Sin[1], 10^6]]` in 0.038 seconds.

Comment: Maybe you could use `Compile`?

Comment: Compiled function evaluates 10^6 times in 4 seconds instead of 7. Still not good. Why is `Sin` so quick and `squareWave` is not?

Comment: Have you tried compiling `J.M.`'s version? It uses only low level functions, I guess, so should be fast.

Comment: J.M.'s version compiled takes 3.5 seconds with `AbsoluteTiming[Do[squareWave[0.3], 10^6]]`. Frankly, setting default values and using only them may speed up the evaluation but it breaks solution of the first problem – this way I can't set duty, phase and period as I would like to (or I have to compile it again for each set of options which is not acceptable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following maps directly to the `List` of values:

```
x = RandomReal[1, 10^6];
squareWave[x_, period_: 1, duty_: (1/2), phase_: 0] := 
       Sign[Mod[x + phase period, period] - (1 - duty) period] (* J.M.'s def. *)
squareWave[x, 1, .5, 0]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* 0.0078 *)
```

If you want to evaluate with multiple period, duty and phase values, stack all values in `List`s as in:

```
x = RandomReal[2, 10^6];
period = RandomReal[1, 10^6];
duty = RandomReal[.7, 10^6];
phase = RandomReal[.5, 10^6];
squareWave[x, period, duty, phase]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* 0.061 *)
```

This is 150 times faster than the sequential approach  `Table[squareWave[x[[i]], period[[i]], duty[[i]], phase[[i]]], {i, 10^6}]`, however it assumes that you know the list of values before running the calculation, which seems to be the case.

Comment: Well this is a very interesting and useful result. I will definitely try to apply it to the real task and mark the answer accepted if it helps. As of now, a quick test shows about 10x improvement in speed so on a good PC it may be enough.

Comment: Somehow I figured that something wonky was going on with either the OP's computer or with how the function I proposed is being applied for it to be "slower" than `Sin[]`, but lost interest in trying to diagnose it.

Answer (score 2):

Using `SawtoothWave` instead of `TriangleWave` seems to run  a little faster.

```
t = RandomReal[1, 10^6];
pulseTrain[t_, period_, duty_, phase_, a_] := 
  0.5 a (1 + Sign[SawtoothWave[t/period + (1 - duty/2) + phase] - (1 -duty)]);
pulseTrain[t, 1, .5, 0.3, 1]; // AbsoluteTiming

(* ~0.101 *)
```

When I use `TriangleWave`, I have

```
x = RandomReal[1, 10^6];
squareWaveAlt[period_, duty_, phase_, x_] := 
  Sign[TriangleWave[x/period - phase] - 1 + 2 duty];
squareWaveAlt[1, .5, 0, x]; // AbsoluteTiming

(* ~0.192 *)
```

This seems to take about twice as long, and I'm not sure why that is.

Comment: It might be better to use `UnitStep[]` + `Mod[]` instead: `pulseTrain[t_, period_, duty_, phase_, a_] := a UnitStep[Mod[t/period + (1 - duty/2) + phase, 1] - (1 - duty)]`